# question about parsing urdf file

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the urdf /Tutorials/ Create your own urdf file: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file, and run `check_urdf my_robot.urdf`, but the answer is:

```
Error:   Error document empty.
         
at line 72 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp

ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

and I can't find the file of build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp, I don't know how to solve it, anyone could help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223623/question-about--parsing-urdf-file/) by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/215648/dont-understand-how-to-parse-urdf-file/?answer=215660#post-id-215660) .

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on 2016-01-07**:
I followed this answer but the same question still appeared.

```
 xu@xu-ThinkPad-SL410:~$ cd   ~/catkin_ws/src/Learning_tutorials/urdf
        xu@xu-ThinkPad-SL410:~/catkin_ws/src/Learning_tutorials/urdf$ check_urdf my_robot.urdf
Error:   Error document empty.
         at line 72 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-07**:
Can you try with full path to URDF?

**Comment by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on 2016-01-07**:
Do you mean running  check_urdf  /home/xu/catkin_ws/src/Learning_tutorials/urdf/my_robot.urdf directly to parse my file? I have tried that way ,but still failed.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-07**:
Are you sure that your path is OK? Can you check your file location respecting lower/upper case letters?

**Comment by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on 2016-01-07**:
I'm sure that my path is correct. But when I run another urfd file"01-myfirst.urdf", which is in the same package with "my_robot.urdf", it succeeded.

xu@xu-ThinkPad-SL410:~/catkin_ws/src/urdf_tutorial/urdf$ check_urdf 01-myfirst.urdf
robot name is: myfirst
Successfully Parsed XML